# SQL Pivot function for healthcare diagnosis codes

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I'm trying to pivot data in my query (SQL Server 2008 R2) and I only need 2 columns pivoted but there may be up to 20 columns after the pivot. Here is my test data with up to 5 diagnosis codes:

```
pid   DiagnosisCode
111   145.9
111   17.43
111   17.84
111   196.2
111   202.81
112   204.21
112   249.71
112   263.8
112   145.9
113   269.8
113   276.7
```

The output I'm trying to get looks like this:

```
    pid  | code1  | code2 | code3 | code4 | code5 | code6 | code... | code20
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
    111    145.9    17.43   17.84   196.2   202.81  NULL    NULL     NULL
    112    204.21   249.71  263.8   145.9   NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
    113    269.8    276.7   NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL     NULL
```

The code I have is :

```
select pid, DiagnosisCode
from
(select pid, DiagnosisCode, row_number() over(partition by pid order by pid) 
as seq
 from #temp  
) as src
pivot
(min(DiagnosisCode)
for seq
in (DiagnosisCode)) pvt
```

For whatever reason, this function isn't clicking with me.I know that the MIN() aggregate function is required, but I don't need one in my output. I added the ROW_NUMBER() line so there would be a sequence field after reading one post, but I'm not sure why its needed. I've been reading all the other Pivot posts here and on other sites. I know this has been gone over many times on this site, but if you could help me understand what else I need in my query to get this to work I would be grateful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to Fix your columns; the SQL Pivot table is different from Access,  this is an example

```
declare @t as table (pid int ,  DiagnosisCode decimal(10,1)) 
insert @t select 111 ,  145.9
insert @t select 111 ,  17.43
insert @t select 111 ,  17.84
insert @t select 111 ,  196.2
insert @t select 111 ,  202.81
insert @t select 112 ,  204.21
insert @t select 112 ,  249.71
insert @t select 112 ,  263.8
insert @t select 112 ,  145.9
insert @t select 113 ,  269.8
insert @t select 113 ,  276.7


select * from @t

select pid
,code1
,code2
,code3
,code4
,code5
,code6
,code7
,code8
,code9
,code10
,code11
,code12
,code13
,code14
,code15
,code16
,code17
,code18
,code19
,code20
from
(

select pid, DiagnosisCode, 'code' + cast(row_number() over(partition by pid order by pid) as varchar(2))
as seq
 from @t  
) as src
pivot
(min(DiagnosisCode)
for seq
in (
code1
,code2
,code3
,code4
,code5
,code6
,code7
,code8
,code9
,code10
,code11
,code12
,code13
,code14
,code15
,code16
,code17
,code18
,code19
,code20
)) pvt



pid  code1  code2  code3   code4   code5  code6  code7  .... code20
---- ------ ------ ------- ------- ------ ------ ------      -------
111  145.9  17.4   17.8    196.2   202.8  NULL   NULL        NULL
112  204.2  249.7  263.8   145.9   NULL   NULL   NULL        NULL
113  269.8  276.7  NULL    NULL    NULL   NULL   NULL        NULL
```

Comment: Thank you. I actually came from a Foxpro background so I guess its what I revert to when I don't  understand something.